# Does a Playstation 3 support Jumbo Frames?

Tags: networking, ps3

So I basically want to transfer some media from my PC to the Playstation 3 over my Gigabit Ethernet network.  I noticed my transfer speeds aren't that hot, and I verified that I DO have a Gigabit Ethernet connection on my PC and PS3 and that Jumbo Frames are supported on both the Gigabit Switch (a cheapo Trendnet) and on the PC.

However, some Googling doesn't seem to have gotten any answers about whether or not the PS3's own Gigabit network adapter supports this.  Seeing how I can only set the MTU value up to 1500, I'm leaning towards a no, but anyone can site evidence that the network adapter on the PS3 can or cannot support Jumbo Frames?

Comment: This should not have been migrated here from superuser.com.

Comment: @jason404 can you explain?

Comment: I think your real problem is getting the rest of your network to support jumbo frames... I haven't run into many consumer grade routers (not running dd-wrt, tomato ect.) that can actually support jumbo frames.

Comment: Well, my network is on a WRT54Gv4, but my PC and PS3 are both connected to a gigabit switch, which is connected to the router, so neither the PC or the PS3 is going through what could potentially be the bottleneck (the router).  It's a cheapo Trendnet GreenNet one; I'm currently getting an HP 1410 Procurve 8-port Gigabit Switch to replace this to see if I can get better performance out of it.

Comment: how on earth did this get here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please be aware that on any reasonable GigE interface, the throughput difference between standard and jumbo frames is less than 10%, probably less than 5%. Between any two GigE-equipped MacBooks, I can get ~945mbps of TCP throughput on standard sized frames. Jumbo frames may push that to 980 or 990, but that's not a huge improvement.

If your transfer times are slow, the lack of jumbo frames is probably not your problem.

Comment: I'm actually getting about half that throughput between the PS3 and the Windows 7 PC.  I get faster transfer times between my Windows 7 PC and a gigabit-capable Windows 7 laptop, so I'm assuming it's some sort of hardware limitation of the PS3 that's causing it.  Thanks.